# Adding the email values to the database

Tags: c#

My sample code:

[image: My sample code]

I just want to get these from,subject,to and body of the mail to my database.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not picture

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your goal by following this approach.

```
...
smtp.Send(mail);
SaveMessage(mail);
...

public void SaveMessage(MailMessage mail)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING"))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE(From, To, Subject, Body) VALUES(@FROM, @TO, @SUBJECT, @BODY)", conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var param = new SqlParameter("@FROM", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    {
                        Value = mail.From
                    };
                    var param2 = new SqlParameter("@TO", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    {
                        Value = mail.To
                    };
                    var param3 = new SqlParameter("@SUBJECT", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    {
                        Value = mail.Subject
                    };
                    var param4 = new SqlParameter("@BODY", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    {
                        Value = mail.Body
                    };
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }            
        }
```